# Is there a way to use custom field delimiter for loading a delimited file into BigQuery using Talend?

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

I would like to use this delimiter `|@#|` instead of a comma

sample record

> AA|#@|--|#@|Not Available|#@|0|#@|

I expect the record in BQ to be like this

> AA --  Not Available  0

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Check this answer and let us know of it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700064/1031958

Comment: Thanks for checking. The answer is not applicable to Talend.

Comment: Sorry unfortunatly I don't have any expiriance with Talend however per Talend [documentation](https://help.talend.com/reader/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/WwuniyNr4hf4hn62WSyQww) you should be able to use the _Field Separator_ in the Advance Section. Can this solve your problem?

Comment: Tried but get error    ----->        java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed: BigQueryError{reason=invalid, location=gs://XXXXX.dat, message=Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.}
 at

Comment: I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55945232/edit) your question with all those details and maybe you will need Talend team to address this

Answer (score 2):

Usually in such case you do following

1. Load data as one column into BigQuery table
2. Split one column to as many as you need using SPLIT(col, '|#@|')[OFFSET(N)] pattern

There can be variations of how to write it - for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col1, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] col2, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] col3, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] col4
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(col, '|#@|') AS e)])
```

you can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'AA|#@|--|#@|Not Available|#@|0|#@|' AS col
)
SELECT 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] col1, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] col2, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] col3, 
  e[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] col4
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(col, '|#@|') AS e)])
```

with result

```
Row col1    col2    col3            col4     
1   AA      --      Not Available   0
```

Hope you can adapt above to your use case

Comment: Thanks. Looking for answer to do it Via Talend and not in BQ(Cost & performance. Loads are in TB). Since BQ allows multi Character delimiter, why would Talend not take it. I am able to make it work with ","(comma delimiter)